# Safari not processing animaitonend

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, css-transitions

I am developing a platform game style site, and it is functioning correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but it seems the animationend event is not processing in Safari.

**Class Assign**

```
$(document).scroll(function(){

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
                if (e.which == '39') {
                    $('#mainSprite').attr("class","cycleR");
                }   
                else if (e.which == '37'){
                    $('#mainSprite').attr("class","cycleL");
                }
                else if (e.which == '38'){
                    $('#mainSprite').attr("class","cycleUp");
                }

                else {
                    $('#mainSprite').removeClass("cycleR");
                }
            });
```

**Event Listener**

```
document.getElementById("mainSprite").addEventListener("animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd", function(event){
var windH = window.innerHeight;
var pos = $(document).scrollLeft();

console.log (pos);
console.log (windH);


if (event.animationName === "jump"){

    if ( windH >= 580 && pos >= 635 && pos <= 765 ||  
         windH < 580 && windH >= 480 && pos >= 720 && pos <= 810 ||
         windH < 480 && pos >= 645 && pos <= 725 ) {

    fire event

    }

}
```

**CSS Class**

```
.cycleUp {
background: url(Image) no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;

animation: jump .35s;
-webkit-animation: jump .35s;
-moz-animation: jump .35s;
-ms-animation: jump .35s;
-o-animation: jump .35s;
```

}

**CSS Animation**

```
@keyframes jump {
0%  {bottom: 50px;}
100% {bottom: 155px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes jump {
    0%  {bottom: 50px;}
    100% {bottom: 155px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes jump {
    0%  {bottom: 50px;}
    100% {bottom: 155px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes jump {
    0%  {bottom: 50px;}
    100% {bottom: 155px;}
}
```

When the user has reached a certain point on the screen and triggered the jump animation, an event should fire. The console isn't logging any errors regarding the function, so I cannot see why it's not firing.

Comment: You shouldnt put links to external websites in questions

Comment: @Keir I removed the link.